# How do I group consecutive integers in sas?

Tags: sas, grouping, sequential

I would like to group consecutive integers in sas.

```
data h;
input integer temperature;
cards;
1 33
2 33
3 34
5 35
6 37
9 33
10 34
;
run;
```

I would like my output to look like this

```
1 33 1
2 33 1
3 34 1
5 35 2
6 37 2
9 33 3
10 34 3
```

Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: I could not understand the full concept of retain.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example? or the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the DIF and retain function. Note that your criteria and example don't match. You say consecutive but seem to imply increase of 0 OR 1.

DIF calculates the difference between current and previous observation. RETAIN holds a value across rows until it's explicitly changed.

```
Data want;
Set have;
 Retain group 0;
 Temp_dif = dif(temp);
 If temp_dif > 1 then group + 1;
 Run;
```

EDIT:

```
Data want;
Set have;
 Retain group 0;
 INT_dif = dif(integer);
 If int_dif > 1 then group + 1;
 Run;
```

Comment: `group + (temp_dif > 1);` is probably how I'd do it, particularly as you can then use dif(temp) directly in that (`group + (dif(Temp) > 1);`), but this way is probably better for beginners.

Comment: Also - it looks to me that the groups are based on `integer` not on `temperature`, hence the apparent discrepancy when you look at temperature.

Comment: @Joe is correct, can modify this by changing temperature to integer.